Polynomial $P(x) = x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + ... + a_{0}$ is such that for every $x$, the following holds: $(x+100)P(x) - xP(x+1) = 1$.

Polynomial $P(x) = x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + ... + a_{0}$ is such that for every $x$,  the following holds: $(x+100)P(x) - xP(x+1) = 1$. Find $a_{0} + a_{n-1} + P(-50)$.

It's easy to find $a_{0}$, but not $a_{n-1}$ and $P(-50)$ without finding $P(x)$.
After some steps I got $P(x) = (x+1)(x+99)Q(x) + \frac{1}{100}$.
Putting back to the polynomial equation, not getting anything useful.

On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1280517p6734520, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1163571p5549665 – found with Approach0

In each of them, after $P(x) = xQ(x) + \frac{1}{100}$ there's this transformation: $(x+100)Q(x) = (x+1)Q(x+1)$ not getting how it comes and from where exactly

If $Q(x) = P(x)-{1\over 100}$ then $$(x+100)Q(x) = xQ(x+1)$$
So $x=0$ and $x=-99$ are zeroes for $Q$ and hus $$Q(x) = x(x+99)Q_1(x)$$ and thus:
$$(x+99)Q_1(x) = (x+1)Q_1(x+1)$$
So $x=-1$ and $x=-99$ are zeroes for $Q_1$ and thus $$Q_1(x) = (x+1)(x+98)Q_2(x)$$ and thus:
$$(x+98)Q_2(x) = (x+2)Q_2(x+1)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$(x+51)Q_{49}(x) = (x+49)Q_{49}(x+1)$$
So $x=-49$ and $x=-51$ are zeroes for $Q_{49}$ and thus $$Q_{49}(x) = (x+51)(x+49)Q_{49}(x)$$ and thus:
$$Q_{50}(x) = Q_{50}(x+1)$$
So $Q_{50}$ is constant polynomial and thus $$P(x) = x(x+1)\cdots (x+49)(x+51)\cdots (x+98)(x+99) + {1\over 100}$$

How in the second step that transformation $(x+100)Q(x) = (x+1)Q(x+1)$ comes immediately ??

@Winther: the leading coefficient of $P$ is $1$, thus also the constant factor.
